# Symfony cannot find the template file

Tags: php, symfony

I have follow all the steps related to Symfony installation, and I try the examples of the Symfony book (provided by the Symfony web site). Currently I am on Controllers chapter (5) and I try the following code:

```
namespace MyBundle\FrontBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('front_buy'), 301);
    }

    public function buyAction(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render(
            'Hello/buy.html.twig',
            array(
                'name' => 'Nikos'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
INFO - Matched route "front_buy" (parameters: "_controller": "MyBundle\FrontBundle\Controller\HelloController::buyAction", "_route": "front_buy")
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "Hello/buy.html.twig"." at /var/www/projects/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128
```

Context: {"exception":"Object(InvalidArgumentException)"}

I know is not something fancy, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

My view file is under the following path : `./src/MyBundle/FrontBundle/Resources/views/Hello/buy.html.twig`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to render it with the following syntax:

```
$this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig')
```

or with this syntax

```
$this->render('@BlogBundle/Blog/index.html.twig')
```

An Example:

```
$this->render('@FrontBundle/Hello/buy.html.twig)
```

More information can be found on the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle), also refering to symfonys [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html) templates should be stored in `app/Ressources/views`

Comment: I just used the `return $this->render('@MyBundleFrontBundle/Hello/buy.html.twig', array('name' => 'Nikos' ) );` and didn't worked, I will try the second form as well and I will come back again.

Comment: Try `return $this->render('@FrontBundle/Hello/buy.html.twig`)

Comment: I try the second form as well that is the followin : `return $this->render('WPLionFrontBundle:Hello:buy.html.twig', array('name' => 'Nikos'));` and I get the following error : `CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Unable to find template "WPLionFrontBundle:Hello:buy.html.twig"." at /var/www/projects/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 128`

Comment: The templating documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle
Also you can put your template in the `app/Resources/views` directory.

Comment: @Andreysobkanyuk you're right, did a typo there, will fix it in a second

Comment: No problem. Please attach the link to documentation and maybe also to [Symfony Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html) as `app/Resources/views` directory there is the recommended directory.

Answer (score 0):

in "app/config/config.yml" be sure to have this:

```
framework:
# ...
templating:
  engines: ['twig']
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was really related to the specific version of Symfony.
My project used to be run with Symfony 2.8.19. I tried to migrate it to another Linux 
 evironment (uning symfony2.8.42) and then I got the very same error with the same code (very wierd).

I tried the solutions mentioned before and none worked like using :
`$this->render('@BlogBundle/Blog/index.html.twig')`
or 
`$this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:index.html.twig')`.

After several tries, I found the problem. In fact, in my old env, I had :

`return $this->render('XxxxxBundle:Default:zzzz.html.twig';`

But the problem was with Capitalized **Default** because the real path was with an uncapitalized **default**

so changing it to the following fixed the problem in my new env:

`return $this->render('XxxxxBundle:default:zzzz.html.twig';`